# Create multiple users roles and views at the same time

Tags: 7

I'm using D7, I need to create views and user roles, when I'm using the interface mode, it takes me too much time, how can I do that using code? or could you please suggest to me a module to install, that can create, for example 10 roles at the same time, or cloning a view 5 times at the same time.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to programmatically create roles (and ideally set permissions for those roles), as well as create a view via code would be to use the [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module. Views can be exported to an array of settings which can then be added with a feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up Drush, which is is a command line shell and Unix scripting interface for Drupal, then you can create a role with the command:

drush role-create

This command accepts and requires 2 arguments, the first one defines the machine name of the role and the second one the human readable name. For example:

drush role-create 'my_new_role' 'My New Role'

Would create the role 'My New Role' with a machine name 'my_new_role'

Drush can also be used to quickly create views. Due to the variety of possible setups depending on your use case, it is probably best to start by looking at the documentation on https://drushcommands.com